# Not able to locate element in chrome by using appium java

Tags: java, appium

I am learning appium and trying to perform a basic google search operation in appium java. The code I have written is:

```
package com.MavenTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class StartChrome {

    @Test
    public void test1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "790dc03c"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", true);

        // Create object of AndroidDriver class and pass the url and capability that we

        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        // "D:\\workspace\\AppiumTest\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Open URL in Chrome Browser
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        System.out.println("Title " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name("Search")));

        driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("google");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElementByName("Gogle Search").click();
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

error I am getting when trying to sendkeys is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to
>   io.appium.java_client.MobileElement

Answer (score 0):

MobileElement is derived from RemoteWebElement.

If you write code like this:

```
driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("google");
```

You are trying to cast a RemoteWebElement to one of its subclasses MobileElement.

java.lang.ClassCastException Issue comes if you directly access the method like below:

```
driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("google");
```

**WorkAround:** You have to cast to the MobileElement like below:

```
MobileElement find = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("google");
```

Comment: Isn't there any workaround so that I don't have to case it to MobileElement everytime?

Comment: Tried this workaround but the issue still exists the same. I What you suggested was to explicitly type cast to MobileElement which it was already trying to do by implicit type casting. Therefore, issue remains same. Is the above code correct, have I instantiated the driver object correct?

Comment: Let me provide more info, the dependencies I am using in my pom.xml are as below:         <!-- Appium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, upgrading Appium Client library fixes it.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```